# Django_filters Widget Customize

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates, django-filter

How Can I Customize Widgets in Django_filters?
I tried To Did Like This But There its make Value in Select Field Gone[Image When Adding Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rsihl.jpg), and When i removed the widget the value is shown [Image When Remove Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r0Dr.jpg),
Sorry for my bad English, Thanks Before

```
class CustomerOrderFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    product = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    status = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('customer', 'date_created', 'updated',)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ChoiceField` is generic, you need to explicitly provide `choices` in your `product` field

```
class CustomerOrderFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    product = django_filters.ChoiceFilter( 
        # replace choices with the choices defined in your order model or just copy it over
        choices=<PRODUCT_CHOICES>,
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```