# How can I remove "multiple" attribute from django_filters form select field?

Tags: python, django, django-filter

Im trying to create a filter form for a table using django-filter.
I have the filter working for the fields I want, however for the two ManyToMany fileds in my model, django_filters is creating a select field with the multiple attribute, I do not want that multiple attribute how can I remove it?

Here is my model (partial)

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    abilities = models.ManyToManyField("capa.CapaType" blank=True)
    responsibilities = models.ManyToManyField(Responsibilities, blank=True
    ...
    ...

Class Responsibilities(models.Model):
    ...
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    ...
```

capa.CapaType is similar to roles just elsewhere in the project

filter.py

```
import django_filters
from .models import Employee

class EmployeeFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('abilities', 
            'responsibilities')
```

From what I have read on various other stack overflow questions such as this [Django_filters Widget Customize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62561732/django-filters-widget-customize), I should be able to set the widget style in filter.py, but when I tried something similar to the following in the EmployeeFilter class;
`responsibilities = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=Employee.responsibilities.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))`

I get this error in the server console;

```
AttributeError: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'
```

Removing "all()" gives me this error when I try to load the page

```
'ManyToManyDescriptor' object is not iterable
```

Any ideas how I can make these fields non multiple?

Thanks

**Edit**

I now have a non multi select box for my filters however the options aren't being marked as selected when chosen, I'm not sure how to fix that, heres what I have now that gives me a single selector

```
responsibilities 
 = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=Responsibilities.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a specific employee before accessing responsibilities, for example:

```
responsibilities = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=Employee.objects.get(pk=1).responsibilities.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

But that is not useful, you can write this:

```
responsibilities = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=Responsibilities.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

Instead of `Responsibilities.objects.all()` you can filter the queryset.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works to a point, i've updated my question to include the example that worked, but it now gives me a non multiple selector which is great, however its not setting the selecting attribute on any option when you select it in the web page, any idea what could be going on here? Another question i have is you said "Instead of Responsibilities.objects.all() you can filter the queryset." could you update your answer to give an example of how that would look? i've tried playing around but no luck