# Django-filter -- How to create a date Filter for 2 different models

Tags: django, django-filter

I have 2 models; Invoice and Expense. Both have a date field. I want to create a django-filter where I put a start-date and end-date and get the result on 2 differents table in the same HTML page. So far I need to use 2 different filters and if I put the date in the Invoice Filter it clears the Expense Filter. Same if I put the date in the Expense Filter it clears the Income Filter.

Here is my filters.py

```
class DashboardIncomeFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
start_date = DateFilter(field_name = "invoice_date", lookup_expr='gte', label='Start Date')
end_date = DateFilter(field_name = "invoice_date", lookup_expr = 'lte', label = 'End Date')
class Meta:
    model = Invoice
    fields = '__all__'
    exclude = ['invoice_slug', 'therapist', 'invoice_date', 'service', 'customer', 'invoice_no', 'price', 'quantity', 'total', 'payment', 'balance']


class DashboardExpenseFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
exp_start_date = DateFilter(field_name = "expense_date", lookup_expr='gte', label='Start Date')
exp_end_date = DateFilter(field_name = "expense_date", lookup_expr = 'lte', label = 'End Date')
class Meta:
    model = Expense
    fields = '__all__'
    exclude = ['expense_date', 'vendor', 'expense_category', 'description','amount']
```

Than on my dashboard.html

```
{% block content %}

<center><h3>DASHBOARD</h3><br/>
    <h3>Todays Date: {{ month }} {{ current_day }}, {{ year }} @ {{ current_time }}</h3><br/>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card card-body"><h4>Incomes Filter</h4><br/>
                <form method="get">
                    {{ ResultFilter.form }}
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                    Search...</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'Dashboard' %}" role = "button">Reset</a>
                </form>
            </div><br/>
            <table style="width: 80%" class="table table-primary table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>        
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Total Incomes</th>
                        <th scope="col">Total Threatments</th>
                        <th scope="col">Days Open</th>  
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="row">{{ income_total }} IDR</td>
                        <td scope="col">{{ threatments }}</td>
                        <td scope="col">{{ days_open }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div><br/>

        <div class="col">
            <div class="card card-body"><h4>Expenses Filter</h4><br/>
                <form method="get">
                    {{ OutcomeFilter.form }}
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                    Search...</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'Dashboard' %}" role = "button">Reset</a>
                </form>
            </div><br/>
                <table style="width: 80%" class="table table-primary table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>        
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Total Expenses</th>
                            <th scope="col">Personnal Expenses</th>
                            <th scope="col">Profit +/-</th>   
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td scope="col">{{ expense_total }} IDR</td>
                            <td scope="col">{{ personnal_expense }} IDR</td>
                            <td scope="col">{{ profit }} IDR</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><br/>
```

Finally, my views.py

```
ResultFilter = DashboardIncomeFilter(request.GET, queryset=invoice_list)
invoice_list = ResultFilter.qs

OutcomeFilter = DashboardExpenseFilter(request.GET, queryset=expense_list)
expense_list = OutcomeFilter.qs
```

All the fields are excluded since I only want to filter on the invoice_date and expense_date field at the same time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit whichever of the filters you specified, it does a GET request with the otther two filter values belonging to the other table not specified.

I've never tried this, but I expect that you can force it to submit all four with either filter submit by defining some null filters. same name as the other table, a method argument, pointing at a method that does nothing at all. Something like

```
class DashboardIncomeFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    start_date = DateFilter(field_name = "invoice_date", lookup_expr='gte', l  abel='Start Date')
    end_date = DateFilter(field_name = "invoice_date", lookup_expr = 'lte', label = 'End Date')

    # no-op filters
    exp_start_date = DateFilter(field_name = "expense_date", 
         method = no_op, widget=forms.HiddenInput, label='Start Date') # label not needed?
    exp_end_date = DateFilter(field_name = "expense_date", 
         method = no_op, widget=forms.HiddenInput, label = 'End Date')

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice  
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['invoice_slug', 'therapist', 'invoice_date', 'service', 'customer', 'invoice_no', 'price', 'quantity', 'total', 'payment', 'balance']

    def no_op( self, qs, name, value):
        return qs
```

Similarly but "mirror imaged" for the other table.

`widget=forms.HiddenInput` ought to make these fields invisible to the users. See Django forms docymentation and [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62561732/django-filters-widget-customize)

Let us know if it works.

In this case, since the filter fields are identical, it might also work if you give the filters for both tables identical names, so the same filter is applied to both tables. Of course, that's assuming you do want to apply the same dates to both tables.

Comment: Thanks for you input. I have tried it but it does not work as is. So far I am getting problem with the noop function. Maybe I need to read more about it. Another way I am looking at it would be to create a Ledger of Entries (Incomes and Expenses) in another table where then I could filter. Still working on it.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is if it's checking whether the field-name exists. In which case you have to attach to hidden filters to a field that does exist: `exp_start_date = DateFilter(field_name = "invoice_date", ...`